# Find prenex normal forms equivalent to the following wfs.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

$(\exists x) A_1^2(x,y) \Rightarrow (A_1^1(x) \Rightarrow \neg (\exists u) A_1^2(x,u))$

By part (f) of Lemma 2.29:
$(\exists x) A_1^2(x,y) \Rightarrow (A_1^1(x) \Rightarrow (\forall u)\neg  A_1^2(x,u))$

By part (c) of Lemma 2.29:
$(\exists x) A_1^2(x,y) \Rightarrow (\forall v)(A_1^1(x) \Rightarrow \neg  A_1^2(x,v))$

By part (c) of Lemma 2.29:
$(\exists x) (\forall w) ( A_1^2(x,y) \Rightarrow (A_1^1(x) \Rightarrow \neg  A_1^2(x,w)))$

Changing bound variables: $(\exists x) (\forall u) ( A_1^2(x,y) \Rightarrow (A_1^1(x) \Rightarrow \neg  A_1^2(x,u)))$

Lemma 2.29 (page 105) ,from Introduction to Mathematical Logic sixth editition , Elliott Mendelson.

[http://sistemas.fciencias.unam.mx/~lokylog/images/Notas/la_aldea_de_la_logica/Libros_notas_varios/L_02_MENDELSON,%20E%20-%20Introduction%20to%20Mathematical%20Logic,%206th%20Ed%20-%20CRC%20Press%20(2015).pdf](http://sistemas.fciencias.unam.mx/%7Elokylog/images/Notas/la_aldea_de_la_logica/Libros_notas_varios/L_02_MENDELSON,%20E%20-%20Introduction%20to%20Mathematical%20Logic,%206th%20Ed%20-%20CRC%20Press%20(2015).pdf)

Is this the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Steps 1 and 2 Ok.

Comment: Step 3 is wrong: According to Mendelson's convention for omission of parentheses (page 48) we have to read the formula as $((\exists x) A_1^2(x,y)) \Rightarrow (A_1^1(x) \Rightarrow \neg (\exists u) A_1^2(x,u))$.